# Colander subclassing SchemaNode

Tags: python, pyramid, deform, colander

I wonder if someone can help me.  I'm explore deform and colander in a new project and was following the documentation about subclassing SchemaNode.  However, whilst the documentation states that

> subclass can define the following methods and attributes: preparer,
>   validator, default, missing, name, title, description, widget, and
>   after_bind.

when I define title, it doesn't seem to come through.  Here is some example code that I'm using:

```
class LocationSchemaNode(colander.SchemaNode):
    schema_type = colander.Int
    title = 'Location'
    missing = None
    validator = colander.Range(
       min=1,
       min_err='Please select a valid location'
    )

class PersonSchema(colander.Schema):

    location_id = LocationSchemaNode()
```

However, when the form is rendered the label for the field is "Location Id" not "Location" as per the title defined in SchemaNode.  If instead I write:

```
class PersonSchema(colander.Schema):

    location_id = LocationSchemaNode(title="Location")
```

Then all appears as I want, but the documentation seems to state I don't need to do this, and if I do it kind of defeats the point of pre-defining a SchemaNode if I have to keep defining fields.

Am I missing something, or is deform doing something that it shouldn't be (I doubt that is going to be the case).  Any help is much appreciated.

Keith

Comment: I would recommend filing a bug with colander/deform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be a bug that was fixed:  https://github.com/Pylons/colander/pull/183

Also, the patch seems to be in the latest available release of colander so an update to the latest version should fix this issue.

### Correction:

The example given in that PR exactly matches this question, but the fix given didn't actually fix that exact issue!  So, I filed another [PR to fix that issue](https://github.com/Pylons/colander/pull/239) and used the example given in #183 as the test.  You can manually patch your own copy if you can't wait for the fix to be introduced into the repo or the next release.

Comment: Sorry Tim, but I just tried this again using a new project (which uses Colander v1.0).  However defining a custom Node with a title value are still ignored completely.

Comment: hmm..  yeah, I just tried your example and you're right... it's still broken.